# Disable certain operating system keystrokes and mouse actions on Cinnamon

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, cinnamon

I'm using Linux Mint, and many of the operating system keystrokes/mouse functions conflict with Blender functions.  For example, when I try to hold down alt and drag, it moves the entire window, rather than doing its supposed action in Blender.  Is there any way that I can disable certain functions like this in Cinnamon on Linux Mint?

Comment: Alt+drag to move the window is implemented by window managers. So it will depend which window manager you are using. Can you add that information to your question, please?

Comment: @Celada It's the Cinnamon desktop environment, but I don't know which windows manager it is.  It's the default one that comes with Mint, but I don't know where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was going into the Windows settings and changing the "Special key to move and resize windows" to Super (the windows button) instead of Alt.
[image]